# How to observe shiluach haken on Twitter

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

*Shiluach Haken* is the commandment of sending away a mother bird before taking her eggs/chicks.

Now, being that Twitter is like a bird (see their logo), how can/should *shiluach haken* be achieved while using Twitter?

What is considered the mother bird, what are the eggs/chicks, how do we take eggs/chicks, and how do we send away the mother?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Inspired in part by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL0K9eJinVE#t=58

Answer (score 6):

Shiluach Hkan is only applicable to kosher birds and their eggs. Twitter has no mesorah and is full of asur items.

Based on the harm the messages do I would call Twitter the the output of "Birds of Prey" which are all not kosher.

Comment: Even birds with no mesorah get shiluach hakan. We don't think they are treif lekula.

Comment: @DoubleAA see edit

Answer (score 4):

You close the Twitter tab, open it again in an incognito window, copy tweets, and don't forget to take the replies to the tweets, too!

Twitter = mother bird

Tweets = eggs

Tweet replies = chicks.